# Pandas: for loop using a combination of two or more values?

Tags: python, pandas

suppose I have the following table:

```
table1 = pd.DataFrame([{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': 140},
     {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': 215},
     {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': 95 },
                       {'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': 1350, 'Feb': 1200, 'Mar': 1404},
                        {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 300, 'Feb': 400, 'Mar': 500}])


table2 = pd.DataFrame(['Jones LLC','Alpha Co', 'Blue Inc', 'Another Company'], columns=['account'] )
```

1. I am trying to create a new column in table2 called "frequency" that counts how many times each value in table2 appears in `table1['account']`. How do I do this?
2. Further to this, let's say I want my for loop frequency count to be applied to only rows in table1 where the value of `table1[Jan]` is greater than 200. How should I write this "multiple criteria" for loop?

Am I thinking about the problem wrongly? Should I have not chosen to use a for loop at all? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` with `value_counts`

Part 1

```
In [876]: table2['freq'] = table2.account.map(table1.account.value_counts())

In [877]: table2
Out[877]:
           account  freq
0        Jones LLC   2.0
1         Alpha Co   2.0
2         Blue Inc   1.0
3  Another Company   NaN
```

Part 2

```
In [884]: table2['freqJAN>200'] = table2.account.map(
                           table1.query('Jan > 200').account.value_counts())

In [885]: table2
Out[885]:
           account  freq  freqJAN>200
0        Jones LLC   2.0          1.0
1         Alpha Co   2.0          1.0
2         Blue Inc   1.0          NaN
3  Another Company   NaN          NaN
```

Or, `table1[table1.Jan.gt(200)].account` inplace of `table1.query('Jan > 200').account`

Comment: Thank you Zero! However, is part 2 not doable from a for loop at all?

Comment: You can loop, but best to avoid for loops when working with pandas for speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
table3 = table1.groupby('account').size().to_frame('freq')
print(table3)
```

Output:

```
           freq
account        
Alpha Co      2
Blue Inc      1
Jones LLC     2
```

Or if you need stats on list of companies:

```
table3 = table1.groupby('account').size().to_frame('freq').reindex(
                                        table2.account,fill_value=0)
print(table3)
```

Output:

```
                 freq
account              
Jones LLC           2
Alpha Co            2
Blue Inc            1
Another Company     0
```